# How do you deal with "Vote for my answer here" social techniques?

Tags: discussion, voting

I've seen quite a bunch of "popular" votes recently which just rephrase a bit the next popular answer but suddenly get a bunch of votes.

I assume this may be down to people using their social network to vote on their responses and I feel this is tweaking a bit the vote system as original posters do not get the recognition that the points system should support.

There is an incentive for users to use their social network, of course, as they receive points. However, seeing this happened a few times I feel less motivated myself to answer in the future.

How will stackoverflow balance against these techniques?

Comment: Examples? How are you picking this up?

Comment: Voting is a voluntary action; people do it because they want to (for whatever reason); as soon as you require votes to be 'arms length', you'll find that the community gets much smaller.

Comment: Are you asking because you're thinking of doing this and wanted to see what checks and balances are in place?

Comment: I actually want to encourage people to vote for another person's answer - I'm 4 bloody votes away from getting the Populist badge...

Comment: @Tom Ritter, I've upvoted the top answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/786918/many-to-many-relationship-use-associative-table-or-delimited-values-in-a-column/786925#786925 and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406604/what-does-operator-mean-in-javascript/1406618#1406618 to get you closer to your goal.

Comment: You're only one vote away on that last one... was a fairly silly question to begin with!

Answer (score 5):

You can always send a broadcast out on twitter for people to vote for your post.

Whether they do or not is up to them.

I can ask you to send me money, but it's still up to you whether or not you send me money.

So long as I'm not coercing anyone into it; it's not a 'crime'.

In reference to Stack Overflow, so long as you don't have [sock puppet accounts upvote your posts](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/), you ought to be fine.

Comment: I'm so sending you cash for this answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think the number #1 balance check in place is the requirement to have at least 15 reputation to be able to vote up. This means that any user in these "social networks" is already eligible to vote answers and questions up anyway since they have contributed to the community already.

Answer (score 0):

Explicit patterns of vote fraud are automatically detected and removed by the reputation algorithm.  Boosters and serial downvoters -- people who vote primarily for or against a particular user -- have their votes removed by a daily fraud detection process.